# Bounded sequence in $L^1$ with no weakly convergent subsequence and bounded sequence in $L^\infty$ with no weakly convergent subsequence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

Can you give two elementary examples that show:

1. a bounded sequence in $L^1$ with no weakly convergent subsequence;
2. a bounded sequence in $L^\infty$ with no weakly convergent subsequence??

---

For the $L^1$ case, I was thinking about an approximation of the Dirac delta, say rectangles of area 1 that get higher and smaller around the origin, but I cannot see if I can make it work. I'm totally lost about the $L^\infty$ case.

Comment: @Ravi I've been thinking about it, but got nowhere.

Comment: Why don't you tell us some of your thoughts? What might be a strategy to find such a sequence in $L^1$?

Comment: @Jason For the $L^1$ case I was thinking about an approximation of the Dirac delta, say rectangles of area 1 that get higher and smaller arond the origin, but I cannot see if I can make it work. I'm totally lost about the $L^\infty$ case.

Comment: @Ravi I edited the question to add my thoughts.

Comment: Your idea for $L^1$ will work. Prepare a sequence of rectangles based at the origin of area one with width $\frac{1}{n}$ and height $n$. This is clearly a bounded sequence. Now try the evaluation at $0$ functional.

Comment: @Ravi I doubt that that functional is continuous on $L^1$

Comment: For $L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ consider $f_n(x)=1$ for $x\leq n$ and 0 otherwise. This function is clearly $L^\infty$, but $f(x)=1$ is not $L^1(\mathbb{R})$

Comment: @AlexR. I do not understand what you're doing. What is this $f$? And why does $f\notin L^1$ prove anything?

Comment: @Riku Is there a reason, why you are not accepting an answer? Is something missing or unclear? If that is the case, please let us know, so that we can adapt our answers.

Answer (score 5):

For the case of $L^1$ your example does work. Let $f_n= n\chi_{(0,1/n)}.$ Suppose, to reach a contradiction, that $f_{n_k}$ converges weakly in $L^1.$ Passing to a further subsequence, which I'll still denote by $f_{n_k},$ we can assume $n_{k+1}/n_k \to \infty.$ Define $g\in L^\infty$ by setting $g=(-1)^k$ on $(1/n_k, 1/n_{k+1}).$ Then $\int_0^1 f_{n_k}g \to -1$ as $k\to \infty$ through odd integers, while $\int_0^1 f_{n_k}g \to 1$ through even integers. Thus $\int_0^1 f_{n_k}g$ fails to have a limit as $k\to \infty,$ contradiction.

---

**Added later**: Why do we need $n_k/n_{k+1} \to \infty?$ Hopefully this will help:

$$\int_0^1 f_{n_k}g = n_k\int_0^{1/n_k} g
= n_k\sum_{j=k}^{\infty}(-1)^j(1/n_j- 1/n_{j+1}) = (-1)^k(1- n_k/n_{k+1}) + r_k.$$

Verify that $|r_k| \le n_k/n_{k+1}.$ Thus the above integrals have the behavior described.

Comment: Why do you need $n_{k+1}/n_k \to \infty$ as $k \to \infty$?

Comment: @user193319 I added to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let me first prove that your example in the $L^1$ case works. Let

$$ f_n=n 1_{(-1/(2n), 1/(2n))}.$$

Assume by contradiction that your sequence has a weakly convergent subsequence and let $f\in L^1$ be the weak limit. Let

$$M_{+,\epsilon}=\{x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus (-\epsilon, \epsilon): f(x)>0\}$$

and

$$M_{-,\epsilon}=\{x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus (-\epsilon, \epsilon): f(x)<0\}.$$

Then we define the functionals $T_{\pm,\epsilon}(g)=\int_{M_{\pm ,\epsilon}} g$. Using weak convergence, one has $T_{\pm , \epsilon}(f)=0$. From this we obtain by the monotone convergence theorem that

$$\Vert f \Vert = \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} T_{+, \epsilon}(f) - T_{-, \epsilon}(f) =0.$$

This implies $f=0$. Define $T(g)=\int_{-1}^1 g$. For every member of our sequence, this functional equal 1, however, $T(f)=0$ which gives you a contradiction.

For the $L^\infty$ case set

$$f_n=(1-n\vert x \vert )1_{(-1/n,1/n)}$$

Similarly as above, one proves that $f=0$ (if it wasn't zero, there would be $C,R>0$ such that $M_+=\{f\geq C\}\cap (-R, R)$ or $M_-=\{f<-C\}\cap (-R, R)$ is not a null set. Consider then the functionals $L_\pm(g)=\int_{M_\pm} g$. By dominated convergence, we get the contradiction $L_\pm (f)=0$). Now define

$$ T: C^0(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \ T(g)=g(0)$$

Using Hahn-Banach, we can extend this functional to all of $L^\infty$. Call the extension $S$. Then we get the contradiction (note that the $f_n$ are continuous and $f_n(0)=1$)

$$ 0=S(f)= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} S(f_n)=1.$$

Comment: For your first example:  Why is this sufficient to show the rising towers sequence has no weakly convergent subsequence? In particular, it might be possible to find a subset of the original sequence (ie subsequence) which does weakly converge.

Comment: @yoshi I don't understand the question. This is exactly what the OP is asking for. A bounded sequence in $L^1$ with no weakly converging subsequence. My proof is by contradiction. I assume by contradiction that there exists a weakly converging subsequence, then I show that it must converge weakly to zero and finally show that this yields a contradiction.

Comment: ah okay, I was getting mixed up with the logic. if you wish, you can add your comment as an answer in the other post and I'll accept it.

Comment: @yoshi I added "by contradiciton" in my answer, I hope it is clear this way.

Comment: Could you explain how to use the Monotone Convergence Theorem in the $L^1$ case

Comment: @Flashhh We have $$T_{+,\varepsilon}(f)-T_{-,\varepsilon}(f)=\int \vert f(x)\vert 1_{\{y\in \mathbb{R} \ : \vert f(y)\vert >\varepsilon\}}(x) dx.$$ Then we have that the integrand is positive and increases is $\varepsilon$ decreases. As it converges pointwise to $\vert f\vert$ we get $$\lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0^+} T_{+,\varepsilon}(f)-T_{-,\varepsilon} =\Vert f\Vert_{L^1}.$$