# A Clarification on Weakly Convergent Subsequences From Another Post

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

The [first example here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2363014/bounded-sequence-in-l1-with-no-weakly-convergent-subsequence-and-bounded-sequ) considers rising towers converging to the delta function at the origin. The first part of the first answer shows how to define two different linear operators on the sequence that give different weak $L^1$ limits. However, this is not sufficient to show the rising towers sequence has no convergent subsuquence right? In particular, it might be possible to find a subset of the original sequence (ie subsequence) which does weakly converge.

Comment: In case you are refering to my answer. That is not a all what I do. I show that the weak limit must be zero if it existed and then reach a contradiction. It also does not seem to be what zhw. was doing in his answer. Maybe you want to reread our answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my answer I argued the following way: Assume by contradiction there exists a weakly convergent subsequence. Then I showed that the weak limit must be the zero function which leads to a contradiction.

This way there cannot be a weakly converging subsequence. For a more direct way of proving things one might also check out the answer given by zhw. who uses a functional in a clever way to reach a contradiction.